# Redefining the <=> operator for std::filesystem::path

Tags: c++

Is it possible to redefine the operator for `std::filesystem::path`?

```
strong_ordering operator<=>(const path& _Left, const path& _Right) noexcept
```

If no, is there a better way than creating wrapper around the `std::filesystem::path`?

Comment: Why do you need to redefine the operator? If you want the filesystem paths to be stored in an associative container but in a different order, you are aware that all associative containers have an optional comparator class, right? Just use your own comparator class.

Comment: Note that identifiers `_Left` and `_Right` are reserved

Comment: I'm suspecting that you want to use `std::greater<>`, as in `std::set<std::filesystem::path, std::greater<>>` etc.

Comment: Also note that it's a bad idea to use a path as a key in a map, because there can be multiple paths that point to the same file. Like `~/file.txt` and `/home/me/file.txt`.

Comment: You might resolve the path to an inode number and use that as the key.